# Divide polyline shapefile using R

Tags: shapefile, r, line

I am very new to GIS in R.

I am trying to split every line in a polyline shapefile into segments of three. My original file has 542 lines, so after the transformation I should have the same shapefile but with 1626 lines. I tried the ArcGis split command but my license only allows me to split one line at the time.

Comment: How do you want to split the lines? Equal length? Some of the features are composed of several segments with a lot of space between them. What do you do about those?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. Ideally I would like to split the lines in equal segments or split the lines so no line is longer than a specific amount of km. For the lines with spaces I would try to apply the same process if possible, but I could also drop them if it makes easier to split the other lines.